# How to create custom Transformers for solr DataImportHandler?

Tags: java, solr

I am trying to index data after reading it from database using Data Import Handler but I need to process the data before indexing it to solr... for that I am trying to create custom transformers but I am not able to do so..... I have written the java code as given on http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHCustomTransformer... but they have not given instructions on how to use it....
P.S.> I am quite new to java

i'm not able to load the transformer even after performing all three ways mentioned here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#How_to_Load_Plugins...

in my data-config.xml i've added an entity:

```
<entity name="cod" query=".. " transformer="foo.check">
</entity>
```

java code:

```
package foo;
import java.util.*;
public class check    {
...
...
}
```

Then I have made jar file using command 
"jar cvf foo.jar check.class"
and placed foo.jar inside example/solr/lib after making lib directory inside solr..... I have tried other two methods as well...
i.e. specify lib path inside solrconfig.xml and add foo.jar inside solr.war

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to how to include the class for Solr to use it, please check http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#How_to_Load_Plugins

You can package the class as a jar and add it to the lib folder of your solr core, so that Solr can load the custom plugin classes you have built.

For the reference of the class in the configuration -

The usage is as defined in the [URL](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHCustomTransformer).

You will need to specify the transformer with the full package name in your data-config.xml as follows:

```
<entity name="artist" query="..." transformer="foo.TrimTransformer">
        <field column="artistName" />
</entity>
```

Comment: Thanks Jayendra, but i'm not able to load the transformer even after performing all three ways mentioned there... in my data-config.xml i've added an entity 
<entity name="cod" query="..... " transformer="foo.check">
</entity>
java code:
package foo;
import java.util.*;
public class check    {

Answer (score 2):

This might be related to how you create your jar file. Unpack the jar file and you should find a folder called "foo" and inside this folder there should be check.class, (foo/check.class). I have a feeling you are only putting the check.class file in it and then referencing it using "foo.check". Another way you can check this is to change transformer to just "check", so 'transformer="check"'. The folder hierarchy in the jar file and the fully qualified class name need to exactly match.